# Choose term of coproduct type

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

We work in homotopy type theory. Denote the propositional truncation of a type $A$ by $\|A\|$ and the function type between types $A$ and $B$ by $A \to B$.

Can you construct a term of the following type:
$$
\prod_{A:U_0}\prod_{B:U_0} 
(\|A\| \to A) \times (\|B\| \to B) \to (\|A + B\| \to A + B)
\quad?
$$

Comment: Oh, sorry, I somehow misread the last $\mathrm{Fun}$ as $\simeq$. By the way, why aren't you writing $A \to B$ instead of $\mathrm{Fun}(A,B)$, as is standard? And propositional truncation should be LaTeXed as `\|A\|` to give you $\|A\|$ instead of $||A||$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer can you associatively parse the arrow notation? I am a little unsure regarding that.

Comment: $A \to B \to C = A \to (B \to C)$ by convention.

Comment: The coproduct $A + B$ in your type need not be inhabited (consider $A = B = 0$), so perhaps your title is a bit misleading.

Comment: @AndrejBauer OK I changed the title.

Comment: However, in the case where A and B are both empty, there is a term of the type the OP is asking about.

Comment: To follow up on whether $A\to B$ is associative, think of finite sets. The cardinality of $[n]\to [m]$ is just $m^n$. However, exponentiation of numbers is not associative: $2^{(1^2)}=2$ while $(2^1)^2=4$. So $(A\to B)\to C$ is generally very different from $A\to(B\to C)$.

Comment: Isn't the question equivalent to inhabiting $\Pi (A, B : U) \; \|A + B\| \to \|A\| + \|B\|$?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I can see an implication in one direction.

Comment: You're right, for the other direction we need to know that $A$ and $B$ are propositions, as @Egbert points out to me (on a private channel).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are going to show that in MLTT with propositional truncation the type
$$\textstyle
\prod_{A:U_0}\prod_{B:U_0} 
(\|A\| \to A) \times (\|B\| \to B) \to (\|A + B\| \to A + B)
$$
has no inhabitants. Assume it did.

We shall work in a specific model of MLTT with propositional truncation, namely  assemblies over number realizability. It is not too important what this model is precisely, except for the following facts:

- there is an object of reals $\mathbb{R}$ in which
- $\Pi (x : \mathbb{R}) \; \|(x < 1) + (x > 0)\|$, and
- every map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathsf{bool}$ is constant.

Hoever, using the above type, we may inhabit
$$\Pi(x : \mathbb{R}) \; \|x < 1\| + \|x > 0\|,$$
contradicting the fact that every map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathsf{bool}$ is constant.
To do so, consider any $x : \mathbb{R}$ and instantiate $A = \|x < 1\|$ and $B = \|x > 1\|$ (and use the fact that $<$ maps into propositions).

Comment: So if it has no inhabitants is there an explicit term of the negation?

Comment: No. Because that would violate another model (classical set theory) in which your type is inhabited.

Comment: This type is a much simpler witness of incompleteness than what is provided by Goedel's theorems. Curious.

Comment: That is a feature of intuitionistic logic. With fewer axioms (no excluded middle) it becomes easier to find undecided statements. The point of Gödel's theorems is not to give one particular undecided sentence, but to give a procedure for generating them.